# How to split a cell in python that has json data stored in it?

Tags: python, json, csv

This is how one of the entries looks like in a csv file.

```
[{"task":"T0","task_label":"Draw a box around each person name and transcribe their information.","value":[{"x":661.63330078125,"y":125.96665954589844,"tool":0,"frame":0,"width":131,"height":29,"details":[{"value":"Elizabeth Abbott"},{"value":""},{"value":0},{"value":""},{"value":""}],"tool_label":"Tool name"}]}]
```

Your replies will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you more clearly describe the expected solution? Split where, what format do you want the results in?

Comment: We are looking for x, y, width and the hight values. We wanted to split them so that we can do some analysis.

Comment: So to confirm, your csv has the following pattern multiple lists containing a dictionary like so: [{}], [{}], [{}], or [{}, {}, {}]? Where {} is the data inside the list in your example?

Comment: Thanks for marking the answer and welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of your data is a list of nested dictionaries. Since you can expect the data in the dictionaries to be uniform, you can write a function to extract the data into a simpler format.

The data is extracted into a dictionary where the individual's names are the keys. You may access their details by using their name as a key to the dictionary as the following. If you do need to import the data from CSV I would suggest using pandas pd.readcsv().

```
# Python 3.7
import json

data = """[{"task":"T0","task_label":"Draw a box around each person name and transcribe their information.","value":[{"x":661.63330078125,"y":125.96665954589844,"tool":0,"frame":0,"width":131,"height":29,"details":[{"value":"Elizabeth Abbott"},{"value":""},{"value":0},{"value":""},{"value":""}],"tool_label":"Tool name"}]},
{"task":"T0","task_label":"Draw a box around each person name and transcribe their information.","value":[{"x":765.878,"y":345.1232113123,"tool":0,"frame":0,"width":128,"height":50,"details":[{"value":"George Jetson"},{"value":""},{"value":0},{"value":""},{"value":""}],"tool_label":"Tool name"}]}]"""
data = json.loads(data)

def get_details(data):
    """ Extract the person, height, width, x, and y values from a list of dictionaries and return a single dictionary keyed by the person. """

    result = dict()

    for item in data:
        person = item.get('value')[0].get('details')[0].get('value')
        height = item.get('value')[0].get('height')
        width = item.get('value')[0].get('width')
        x = item.get('value')[0].get('x')
        y = item.get('value')[0].get('y')

        result[person] = {'height': height, 'width': width, 'x': x, 'y': y}

    return result


# extract details to a dictionary
details = get_details(data)

# access details for a specific person
person = 'Elizabeth Abbott'
print(f"{person}'s height is {details[person]['height']}")
print(details[person])

# access details for a specific person
person = 'George Jetson'
print(f"{person}'s height is {details[person]['height']}")
print(details[person])
```

**Console:**

```
Elizabeth Abbott's height is 29
{'height': 29, 'width': 131, 'x': 661.63330078125, 'y': 125.96665954589844}
George Jetson's height is 50
{'height': 50, 'width': 128, 'x': 765.878, 'y': 345.1232113123}
```